# Build a shared library that uses OpenSSL installed on respective Linux machine

Tags: c++, ubuntu, openssl, centos, g++

Is it possible to build a shared library or Linux application that uses OpenSSL installed on respective Linux machines?

For example, when we compile and link, we use "-lssl -lcrypto" similar to this is there any option or solution to use the OpenSSL library installed on the machine on which the application will be running. We can't use "dlopen".

So my application should be built in such a way that when installed on CentOS 7 it should use the default OpenSSL 1.0.2 of CentOS 7 and when installed on Ubuntu 20.04 it should use OpenSSL 1.1.1

How can I achieve it, please?

Comment: Can't you turn it around i.e. define the OpenSSL lib. you used as dependency? With a resp. package manager script, you can ensure that the user is requested to install it if it's not yet there.

Comment: no, those versions of OpenSSL are not compatible. You'll need to statically link your libraries if you want to support both OSs

Comment: @Scheff'sCat Ubuntu only supplies Openssl 1.1 packages and Centos 7 only comes with 1.0 so that won't work

Answer (score 0):

You have five options in my view.

1. Static link OpenSSL
2. Deploy your application with Anaconda packages
3. Deploy your application with Docker container
4. Build separate packages for each OS
5. Force your users to install OpenSSL from source

Comment: Thanks @WilderField for the response. How can this be achieved by docker? If possible can you please share a tutorial? My application will be a server-based GUI application, so it would be good if you can provide few more information on using docker to deploy my application.

Comment: A docker container can contain your prebuilt binaries and their compatible dependencies. You specify how the docker image is built with a Dockerfile. The same docker container can run on any OS and any machine with same CPU arch.

Comment: https://medium.com/geekculture/run-a-gui-software-inside-a-docker-container-dce61771f9

Comment: I’ve not done much GUI work, but consider all your options for implementing a GUI. I don’t think C++ is the easiest solution for that. I know of Electron and Javascript and those were popular a few years back.